# DataTable not working with Bootstrap 4 in Django

Tags: html, jquery, django, bootstrap-4, datatable

I am new to DJango but have experience with Python. I am creating a Notes Sharing Site. Idea is users will upload notes, admin will accept it and only accepted notes are public. The user can see all of its notes including the pending and rejected ones.

Problem:
Admin is able to see all the users. I am heavily using bootstrap for design because I am trying to focus on back-end. I am using bootstrap tables of viewing the users and viewing the notes ( viewing notes works perfectly because I am not using data table in that table ). Real problem is in viewing users ( by admin ), normal bootstrap table is working perfectly but it is not being modified by data-table. I have not used data able in past it is my first time.

HTML code:

view_users.html

```
{% extends 'admin_core.html' %} 
{% load static %} 

{% block head %}
<style>
    td {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>

<scirpt type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></scirpt>
<scirpt type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></scirpt>
<scirpt type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></scirpt>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#user-table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
{% endblock head %} 

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center my-4">Users</h2>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered md-2" id="user-table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Sr. No.</th>
                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Email Address</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    <th>Branch</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for user in users %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ user.user.first_name }} {{ user.user.last_name }}
                    </td>
                    <td
                        class="align-middle"
                        style="text-transform: none !important"
                    >
                        {{ user.user.username }}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ user.contact }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.branch }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.role }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a
                            role="button"
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-sml"
                            href="{% url 'delete_user' user.user.id %}"
                            onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
                            >Delete</a
                        >
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

As this page extends admin_core.html, its code:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required ( not really ) meta data tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Notes Sharing Site - Admin</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Our own CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />

    <!-- Head Block ( to extend the page ) -->
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock head %}
</head>

<body style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <!-- Bootstrap Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="{% url 'admin_home' %}">
            <img src="{% static 'images/icon.png' %}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            Notes Sharing Site - Admin
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- <span class="sr-only">(current) -->

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Public Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin_home' %}">Admin Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="admin/">DJango Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="view-notes" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        View Notes
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="view-notes">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">All</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pending</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accepted</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rejected</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'view_users' %}">View Users</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <a class="btn btn-danger my-2 my-sm-0" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Body Block ( to extend the page ) -->
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock body %}


    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript and JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!--
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for spelling mistake ( English is not my first language ) and any noob coding problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the debug or production version for static files? If the debug one then you need the special url paths and if the production one then you need to have STATIC_ROOT path in your settings.py that points to the static directory where the files will be collected with collectstatic command.

- Or try Check adding these

  import mimetypes
  mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)

Comment: Where do I add it?